# Does the new photos app still try to recognise faces?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

Will the new photos app still try to guess who everyone is in all my photos? I'm really hoping this is one *feature* that was deprecated!

---

**FYI** if anyone is wondering, I personally did not like this feature because it consumed at lot of CPU and kicked my fans up to 100% with no way to limit or control the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a Faces album which will show all recognised faces in your images.

Comment: And it will let you keep recognizing faces if you want to.